# F# constructor fails to build after change of Func arguments order

Tags: f#, constructor, overloading

While refactoring some F# code, I came across a problem which I fail to understand or resolve. I have a class Problem, with 2 constructors, one default for F# consumption, one for C# convenience, which takes in Funcs and "converts" them into F# functions:

```
open System

type Problem<'d, 's> (data: 'd, generate: 'd -> Random -> 's, mutate: 'd -> Random -> 's -> 's, evaluate: 's -> float) =

   member this.Data = data
   member this.Generate = generate this.Data
   member this.Mutate = mutate this.Data
   member this.Evaluate = evaluate   

   new (data: 'd, generator: Func<'d, Random, 's> , mutator: Func<'d, 's, Random, 's> , evaluator: Func<'s, float>) =
      let generate (data: 'd) rng = generator.Invoke(data, rng)
      let mutate  (data: 'd) (rng: Random) (solution: 's) = mutator.Invoke(data, solution, rng)
      let evaluate (solution: 's) = evaluator.Invoke(solution)
      Problem(data, generate, mutate, evaluate)
```

As far as I can tell, this builds and works as expected.

Being somewhat obsessive-compulsive, I noted that the mutator Func in the C#-friendly constructor had a different order for the arguments, so I proceeded and rewrote it this way (first part unchanged):

```
   new (data: 'd, generator: Func<'d, Random, 's> , mutator: Func<'d, Random, 's, 's> , evaluator: Func<'s, float>) =
      let generate = fun (data: 'd) rng -> generator.Invoke(data, rng)
      let mutate = fun (data: 'd) (rng: Random) (solution: 's) -> mutator.Invoke(data, rng, solution)
      let evaluate = fun (solution: 's) -> evaluator.Invoke(solution)
      Problem(data, generate, mutate, evaluate)
```

While the 3 functions seem to have the right signature, the last line fails and displays a red squiggly, telling me that "A unique overload for method 'Problem`2' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window). A type annotation may be needed."

Can anyone help me see what I am missing? I tried to type-annotate the 4 arguments in the last line, to no avail - and I have no idea how to fix this. What also strikes me as odd is that the previous version worked, simply by having 2 arguments reversed in a Func.

Comment: I believe F# does some implicit conversions between `Func` types to curried functions automatically - perhaps this is causing the problem

Comment: I suspect you are right, otherwise I don't understand the type confusion - and that would fit with the "change of argument order" problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the spec (8.13.6) gives:

> The first type-directed conversion converts anonymous function expressions and other function-valued arguments to delegate types.
>   Given:
>
> A formal parameter of delegate type D
>
> ·         An actual argument farg of known type `ty1 -> ... -> tyn -> rty`
>
> ·         Precisely n arguments to the Invoke method of delegate type D
>
> Then:
>
> ·         The parameter is interpreted as if it were written:
>       `new D(fun arg1 ... argn -> farg arg1 ... argn)`

As these conditions apply, the `Func` delegates are converted to curried form, so an ambiguity exists.

Comment: Looks right, thank you for checking the spec! Before accepting the answer, I need to ask: so... what do I do? I would like to expose a Func<> based constructor for C# consumers, parallel to the fun signatures, but I don't see a way to do that unless I create an artificially-different signature (like I had originally). Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Matthias - I think you need an artificial difference, Tomas Petricek or someone else may have a better solution.  Alternatively, you could make the F# version have a record type as an argument which seems more elegant.